# How to get in presto/trino as JSON object columns from mongo?

Tags: mongodb, presto, trino, mongodb-connector-for-bi

I am trying to get in presto, the JSON saved in mongo as Object
Using: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/mongodb.html

I am looking for some way to convert a composite column to a JSON

```
select id, AS_JSON_STRING(en)
from cities
```

Example collection

```
cities
{
   en: { description: "New york", price: 100}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trino MongoDB connector supports JSON type. You need to update `_schema` collection directly for changing the column type.
https://trino.io/docs/current/release/release-360.html#mongodb-connector